# knockoutjs - bindings with parameters triggered on load

Tags: knockout.js

I've been doing a lot of knockoutjs lately, and I came across a strange occurence.

As you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hqXjv/ when you set up a binding to `click: testMethod` then the action fires when the button is clicked.

As you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kxTzM/ when you setup the binding to `click: testMethod('hi')` the action fires both when the button is clicked and on page load (I'm guessing on applyBindings)

Having a parameter isn't necessary to reproduce the problem, if you change the binding to `click: testMethod()` in the first fiddle, you see that it is triggered on page load.

While, yes, I could add another attribute to the element and attempt to use that as a parameter, my question is, is there a way to pass parameters to knockoutjs bindings without triggering them onload.  If this is a bug, so be it, however I just want to know a way to avoid it.

Comment: This bug was driving me insane today, spent half of my day debugging scripts not realising it is a bug. Thx

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I think "Note 2" on this knockout page explains it all:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

You can avoid the problem by either using:

**Anonymous functions:**

```
<button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myFunction(data, event, 'param1', 'param2') }">Click me</button>
```

... or ...

**The bind method:**

```
<button data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 'param1', 'param2')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but there is no explanation why the click event is fired on load..

Comment: Your template is invoking the function straight away rather than passing it an instance of the function - by wrapping it in a new function you're giving is a callback which the invokes your function. It's the way a template is rendered to JavaScript and is common in all template libs

Comment: You can improve this answer by excerpting the relevant information from "Note 2", and/or explaining it.  I've read "Note 2" on the page you link to, but it's not clear to me still why this is happening.  I could spend a few more minutes trying to understand it, but I'd prefer your answer here did that for me.

Answer (score 28):

The following executed the click function on load

```
click: clickSpan()
```

**removing the brackets** as below, the function was not executed onload

```
click: clickSpan
```

(this is explained in note 2 above but it was in cryptic form :-)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this under the following circumstances:

- I was running Visual Studio 2013.
- My knockout project was using TypeScript 1.5.
- I was running my project in chrome using the Visual Studio debugger.
- I had poorly refactored some code and neglected to recompile or re-run the debugger.

Because of this, I believe what happened was I had bad TypeScript that wouldn't compile, only I wasn't getting any warnings or errors to that effect, and edits that I made to my TypeScript were not getting reflected properly in the auto-generated JavaScript files.

It might be uncommon that others will see this, but, I guess a word of warning is that you might run into this, or other unexpected behavior if you're editing TypeScript in place while running the VS debugger. I suspect that I had created the situation that Mark Robinson described in my auto-generated js files, but I did not see that in my TypeScript.