# How to get reference to viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

(Am new to single page apps and knockout, but am familiar with the MVVM concept in WPF/Silverlight.)

I have a simple viewModel with a property called selectedPayPeriodId which is bound to a dropdown using Knockout.  This works.

```
 <select data-bind="options: SelectList, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', value: selectedPayPeriodId"></select>
                <input id="btnRunReport" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Run Report" onclick="doTest()" />
                <p>Selected Pay Period Id:<span data-bind="text: selectedPayPeriodId"></span></p>
```

Now I need to get the value of viewModel.selectedPayPeiriodId from a javascript function so that I can use it in an ajax call to get json from the server.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
var doTest = function() {
    //How to get reference to viewModel?
    alert(viewModel.selectedPayPeriodId); //Error: viewModel is undefined.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put doTest in your view model and then bind to it using `data-bind: "click: doTest"`. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

```
function myViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.selectedPayPeriodId = ko.observable();

        this.doTest = function() {
            alert(self.selectedPayPeriodId());
        };
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: doTest"/>
```

Comment: This works.  However, I do get doTest() firing when the page first loads.  If I then click the button, the event fires just fine.  Any idea why it might be firing early?

Comment: Try this: click: function(data,event) { $root.doTest(); }

Comment: And try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891282/knockoutjs-bindings-with-parameters-triggered-on-load

Comment: The other solution is: `click: doTest` instead of `doTest()~ I updated the answer to reflect this.